# Jade template include child templates with block

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, pug, template-engine

I have following file structure:

```
views
 |
 |-index.jade
 |-layout.jade
 |-partials
   |-projects.jade
   |-tasks.jade
```

Layout defines a block called content which is used by index to define the body.
layout.jade

```
!!!
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf8')
  body(ng-app="myapp")
    block content
```

index.jade

```
extends layout
block content
  ..
    div(class='col-md-4 border projectOverview')
      block projects //embedding childs template
    div(class='col-md-8 border projectOverview')
      block tasks //embedding child template
```

partials/projects.jade

```
extends ../index
block projects
  p There are {{projects.length}} projects
```

But when I test the whole stuff with the jade compiler on cmd (`jade -P views/index.jade`) nothing gets included. I tried with `include` instead of `block`, as I read in another post. That worked. But I want these 2 (projects and tasks) templates the whole time displayed in index.jade/html. They will get updated from angular.

The output after compiling to html is the following:

```
...
    <div ng-view class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 border projectOverview">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 border projectOverview">
          </div>
    </div>
...
```

I don't know how to get that running or if include would be the better approach?

Comment: I don't understand, the compiled projects.html should have the projects and tasks. Why are you checking index.html for that?

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing me to the right direction, I thought that tasks and projects are compiled to into index.html, but instead it was the other way around. With include I get the behaviour I expected.